# Hide show div front and back per div behaviour function/toggle jquery

Tags: jquery, toggle, hide, show, closest

I want to create a sort of toggle between 2 div's with classes: front and back. Both in .entry-footer. It's wotking allright. But the last step is that it needs to correct back to normal : front visible, back hidden... And not all backs should be hidden only the **klikobj** (=clikobject)....
Any suggestions to optimize this code?

https://jsfiddle.net/ontwerp73/osg8up7a/2/#&togetherjs=UojQmsnD2F

```
$('.entry-footer').on('click', function(event) { 
    var klikobj = event.target; 
    $(klikobj).closest('.front').hide(); 
    $(klikobj).next('.back').show(); 
    $('.back').on('click', function(event) { 
        $(klikobj).closest('.front').show(); 
        $(klikobj).next('.back').hide(); 
    }); 
});
```

The html base :

```
<footer class="entry-footer">
<div class="front" style="display: block;">
<br>Titel: Mr Robot<br>Regisseur: mr Bean<br>Producent: Spielberg<br>Info: extra extra! extra extra! extra extra! extra extra! <br>Productiejaar: 2017              </div>
<div class="back" style="display: none;">
<br>Beschrijving: Een robot is een programmeerbare machine die verschillende taken uit kan voeren. Hierin verschilt hij van een numerieke machine, die is geprogrammeerd voor één taak. In de praktijk betekent....</div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to use a toggle() function?

```
$('.entry-footer').click(function() {
  $(this).children().toggle();
});
```

**The working version for multiple divs:**

```
$('.entry-footer').click(function() { 
    var childNum = $(this).children().length;
    $(this).children().each(function(ind, el) {
        if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
            if (ind == childNum - 1){
                $(this).siblings(":first").show();
                $(this).hide();
                return false;
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
                $(this).next().show();
                return false;
            }
       }
   });
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/71uug7fp/)

Comment: one question toggle() is nice for switching between 2 elements. But what about 2+?? : $(this).children().   ... 1st , 2nd and 3rd object? With : [obj]:nth-child(2) of  [obj]:nth-child(3) etc?

Comment: If more than 2, you need another approach. Do you need more than 2? :) Do you mean like front middle and back elements?

Comment: I will post a solution for you tonight if you really need, do not have time for that just now. I see your logic now and what you try to achieve.

Comment: Hi now this is great! Will play with this Sunday... Is very handy for multiple click elements in wordpress/php loops. ;-)

Comment: @amuga3 : one situation that I get this : One ,

Three , One 2, so the 1st and 3rd and second object of 2nd footer.

Comment: Haven't tested properly :( ok, i will have a look how to solve that.

Comment: @Valentijn L : This version is working, I have updated my answer, so have a look. Mark it as a correct answer if you a happy with the result. xD Good luck!

Comment: @amuga3 thanks man, will analyse the code what's happening for learning goal as well as useful for others ;-)